# Is there a way to speed up docker build when using docker build in dind inside a gitlab-ci pipeline?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, docker-in-docker, gitlab-ci.yml

In gitlab-ci pipeline, I use docker-in-docker `dind` to build and push a docker image.

Everytime the job starts, the building process starts from scratch although the changes that have been made affects only the last layer or last few layers.

It is well known that Docker can use cached layers to speed up the building process. This is what happens when running docker directly on localhost for example.

does gitlab-ci uses docker cache by default when docker building with dind? if not, is there a way to tell gitlab-ci to keep/use cached layers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi stage build and push indirect image to image repo. Before each build you can pull that image and use it as a cache.
I made it like that and it helped in my case:

```
build:
  stage: build
  interruptible: true
  script:
    - docker pull $REGISTRY_PATH/<target-image>:runtime-image || true
    - docker pull $REGISTRY_PATH/<target-image>:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA || true
    - docker build --target runtime-image --cache-from $REGISTRY_PATH/<target-image>:runtime-image -t $REGISTRY_PATH/<target-image>:runtime-image apps/my-apps
    - docker build --cache-from $REGISTRY_PATH/<target-image>:runtime-image --cache-from $REGISTRY_PATH/<target-image>:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA -t <target-image>:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA apps/my-apps
    - docker tag <target-image>:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA $REGISTRY_PATH/<target-image>:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
    - docker push $REGISTRY_PATH/<target-image>:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
    - docker push $REGISTRY_PATH/<target-image>:runtime-image
  image: docker:20.10
  services:
    - docker:20.10-dind
```

`runtime-image` is my stage of the build that not change so often.